# WebView inside HubSection does not render page

Tags: webview, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a WebView inside a HubSection in a Hub control:

```
<HubSection x:Name="details_section" ...>
    <!-- ... -->
    <DataTemplate>    
         <WebView x:Name="webView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Height="300"  />
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

The problem is that, when I make it navigate to an HTML string, it does not render the content.

```
// I adjusted and simplified the code
WebView wv = elem.FindName("webView") as WebView;
if (wv != null) {
    wv.NavigateToString(detailTemplate);
}
```

Of course I debugged to see that the method actually gets called. Moreover, the LoadCompleted event gets called as well.

The problem is not due to bad HTML code as I tested with plain "<html><body>hello</body></html>".

Comment: Does the same code work outside of a `Hub`?

Comment: Yes, outside the hub the WebView correctly manages to render the HTML code.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem. I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @W.K.S I have posted what seems to be a solution (please check as it was a long time ago and I do not remember)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the following extension: https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Extensions/WebViewExtension.cs

Use:

```
<ns:MyPage
xmlns:ns="using:mylib" 
xmlns:ext="using:WSLibrary.Extensions" ...>
   <!-- ... -->
   <HubSection x:Name="details_section" ...>
      <!-- ... -->
      <DataTemplate>    
          <WebView ext:WebViewExtensions.HtmlSource="{Binding MyHtmlString}" ... />
     </DataTemplate>
   </HubSection>
   <!-- ... -->
</ns:MyPage>
```

Comment: :Can you explain a bit more. I dont know to use the extension. I copied the contents of WebViewExtension.cs to a file inside my project and i did add "xmlns:ns="using:mylib" 
xmlns:ext="using:WSLibrary.Extensions" . Am getting error in this line  <WebView ext:WebViewExtensions.HtmlSource="{Binding MyHtmlString}". The error says :The name WebViewExtension does not exist in the namespace using WSLibrary.Extensions

Comment: Is your WebViewExtension class inside the namespace WSLibrary.Extensions? (This is basic C# programming... And also note that the xmlns:ns="using:mylib" is pointless..)

Comment: :Thanks. Am new to c# . I think that was the problem

Answer (score -1):

Set `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` of HubSection to `Stretch`.

```
<HubSection x:Name="details_section"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```